# Laravel : change the class li if the user answered the survey

Tags: css, laravel, class, if-statement

I want to change class for each class of

if the user answered the survey before

I tried to use if condition but nothing changed

Controller :

```
public function home(Request $request) 
  {
    $surveys = Survey::get();
    foreach ($surveys as $survey) {
    $user_id = auth()->user()->id;
    $user_ip = request()->ip();
    $hasAnswer = \App\Answer::where(['user_id'=>$user_id , 'survey_id' => $survey->id, 'last_ip'=>$user_ip])->exists();
    }
    return view('home', compact('surveys','hasAnswer'));
  }
```

view blade :

```
<div class="col-12">
                        <ul class="list-group">
                            @forelse ($surveys as $survey)
                            @if($hasAnswer)
                            <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-success">
                                    <div>
                                        {{ link_to_route('detail.survey', $survey->title, ['id'=>$survey->id])}}
                                        <a href="survey/view/{{ $survey->id }}" title="Take Survey" class="secondary-content"><i class="material-icons">send</i></a>
                                        <a href="survey/{{ $survey->id }}" title="Edit Survey" class="secondary-content"><i class="material-icons">edit</i></a>
                                        <a href="survey/answers/{{ $survey->id }}" title="View Survey Answers" class="secondary-content"><i class="material-icons">textsms</i></a>
                                    </div>
                            </li>
                            @else
                            <li class="list-group-item">
                                <div>
                                    {{ link_to_route('detail.survey', $survey->title, ['id'=>$survey->id])}}
                                    <a href="survey/view/{{ $survey->id }}" title="Take Survey" class="secondary-content"><i class="material-icons">send</i></a>
                                    <a href="survey/{{ $survey->id }}" title="Edit Survey" class="secondary-content"><i class="material-icons">edit</i></a>
                                    <a href="survey/answers/{{ $survey->id }}" title="View Survey Answers" class="secondary-content"><i class="material-icons">textsms</i></a>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            @endif
                            @empty
                                <p class="flow-text center-align">Nothing to show</p>
                            @endforelse
                        </ul>
                    </div>
```

Nothing changed even i tried to answer for some surveys but no class changed

Comment: data exists in `Answer` model for the same user,survey and ip ?

Comment: also your `$hasAnswer` is inside loop so only the last iterate value is returned.. you need to make an array to store all value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public function home(Request $request) 
  {
    $surveys = Survey::get();
    $user_id = auth()->user()->id; // you don't need to iterate over and over again for the same value
    $user_ip = request()->ip();  // you don't need to iterate over and over again for the same value
    foreach ($surveys as $survey) {

    $hasAnswer[] = \App\Answer::where(['user_id'=>$user_id , 'survey_id' => $survey->id, 'last_ip'=>$user_ip])->exists();
    }
    return view('home', compact('surveys','hasAnswer'));
  }
```

blade file:

```
<div class="col-12">
   <ul class="list-group">
      @forelse ($surveys as $key => $survey)
      @if($hasAnswer[$key])
      <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-success">
         <div>
            {{ link_to_route('detail.survey', $survey->title, ['id'=>$survey->id])}}
            <a href="survey/view/{{ $survey->id }}" title="Take Survey" class="secondary-content"><i class="material-icons">send</i></a>
            <a href="survey/{{ $survey->id }}" title="Edit Survey" class="secondary-content"><i class="material-icons">edit</i></a>
            <a href="survey/answers/{{ $survey->id }}" title="View Survey Answers" class="secondary-content"><i class="material-icons">textsms</i></a>
         </div>
      </li>
      @else
      <li class="list-group-item">
         <div>
            {{ link_to_route('detail.survey', $survey->title, ['id'=>$survey->id])}}
            <a href="survey/view/{{ $survey->id }}" title="Take Survey" class="secondary-content"><i class="material-icons">send</i></a>
            <a href="survey/{{ $survey->id }}" title="Edit Survey" class="secondary-content"><i class="material-icons">edit</i></a>
            <a href="survey/answers/{{ $survey->id }}" title="View Survey Answers" class="secondary-content"><i class="material-icons">textsms</i></a>
         </div>
      </li>
      @endif
      @empty
      <p class="flow-text center-align">Nothing to show</p>
      @endforelse
   </ul>
</div>
```

**Note: the code is not tested.**